# Function to return SETOF Table in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-function, quoted-identifier

I'm trying to build a simple function that meets the following criteria (needed to work with Hasura API fwiw [link](https://docs.hasura.io/1.0/graphql/manual/queries/custom-functions.html#supported-sql-functions))

```
Function behaviour: ONLY STABLE or IMMUTABLE
Return type: MUST be SETOF <table-name>
Argument modes: ONLY IN
```

This is the function

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_sum_views(text) RETURNS SETOF page_analytics AS $$
  SELECT prodID, sum(views) FROM page_analytics WHERE prodID = $1 group by prodID
$$ LANGUAGE SQL STABLE;
```

And I get the error: `"column \"prodid\" does not exist"`. I get the same error when I use `page_analytics.prodID`, `"page_analytics.prodID"`, or `\"page_analytics.prodID\"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any table names or column names that include capital letters, always ensure you use doublequotes. Otherwise, they are [converted to lowercase](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS).

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_sum_views(text) RETURNS SETOF page_analytics AS $$
  SELECT "prodID", sum(views) FROM page_analytics WHERE "prodID" = $1 group by "prodID"
$$ LANGUAGE SQL STABLE;
```

Also note, when quoting "page_analytics"."prodID" would also work.